# Error starting Appium session on OSX

Tags: python, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I'm unable to kick off an appium session either by inspector or from webdriver

Appium Version 1.4.13,
OSX V 10.10.5

Appium LOG:

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 1828692D-XXXX-44E2-B901-699E89C43B9X -l 


info: [debug] Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 1828692D-XXXX-44E2-B938-699E89C43B9X -l 

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 1828692D-XXXX-44E2-B938-699E89C43B9X -l \n)","killed":false,"code":2,"signal":null,"cmd":"/bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 1828692D-XXXX-44E2-B938-699E89C43B9X -l ","origValue":"Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 1828692D-257B-44E2-B938-699E89C43B97 -l \n"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 680.025 ms - 418
```

I get the same thing when I kicked off my test as such:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

I've uninstalled everything from ideviceinstaller, appium, node, homebrew and I'm stumped. Any help would rock!

Answer (score 0):

give a try by using this:

```
 new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

i use this in java, hope for python, no much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Aight! I figured it out!  After a little digging, it's safe to say to everyone that posts questions please ask if they are using a simulator or a real device with appium. Once you use a simulator AND you have a UUiD ideviceinstaller will fail.

So if you're swithcing between real and simulator be sure to update your settings. lesson learned.